# File Revisions suspect behavior?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, revisions

New problem seems to have appeared today with GoogleDrive non-native file revisions.

Been successfully updating existing documents in a GoogleDrive account for months now from a C# app via the GoogleDrive API - some files have 40, 60 and even over 100 revisions just fine.

Today when an update is done with a request for new revision and pinned, the existing revision is overwritten and no new revision is created.  Seems to only be on existing, multi-revision files.
Can create a new file and update again and again just fine.

Also tried it through the Google Drive web app instead of the API and getting the same behaviour.
New files can have multiple revisions added to them successfully - existing files do not get new revisions, only replaces head revision instead.