# Google Drive API gives incorrect file metadata

Tags: google-drive-api

Some of the files have incorrect `md5Checksum` and `fileSize` in their File resource (via [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)). It's a critical issue because we use `md5Checksum` to verify our downloads. In our experience, this seems to tend to happen to shared files. An example file that experiences this is `0B7sQRgKvWBSsRDlPN3VmWmhheDg`.

It seems to be happening only recently, together with [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230205/google-drive-file-revisions-behaviour-suspect) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233782/google-drive-not-persisting-put-changes) critical issues.